# iff condition for quadratic residue modulo p when $p\equiv3\mod 4$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences, quadratic-residues

Let $p$ be an odd prime, then we either have $p\equiv 1\mod 4$ or $p\equiv 3\mod 4$. And we have an iff condition for quadratic residue modulo p when $p\equiv 1\mod 4$, which is "$x^2\equiv-1\mod p$ iff $p\equiv 1\mod 4$". I wonder if there is any similar result for $p\equiv 3\mod 4$

Comment: $\nexists x:x^2\equiv -1 \bmod p \text{ iff } p\equiv 3 \bmod 4$? (which is the same result, of course, expressed the other way around).

Comment: Let $p$ be an odd prime....If $p\equiv 3 \mod 4$ and $j \not \equiv 0\mod p,$  exactly one member of  $\{j,p-j\} $ is  a square $\mod p.$... If 
 $p\equiv 1 \mod 4$  and $j\not \equiv 0 \mod p$ then either  both members of $\{j,p-j\}$ are squares $\mod p$ or neither member is a square $\mod p.$